# Make lint syntax error: unexpected end of file running a multi-line shell fragment

Tags: shell, makefile

I have lint target in Makefile

```
lint:
    @echo "Checking with SwiftLint"
    if test -d "/opt/homebrew/bin/"; then
        PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin/:${PATH}"
    fi

    export PATH

    if which swiftlint > /dev/null; then
        swiftlint
    else
        echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
    fi
```

When I run make lint it shows me `syntax error: unexpected end of file`

I've checked with [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and it shows that everything is legit

Comment: Separate from your question, but `which swiftlint` is in most `/bin/sh` implementations quite inefficient -- it has to start a separate executable called `which`. Consider using `command -v swiftlint`, which is built into all POSIX-compliant shells, and is in better shells able to use or create cached PATH lookups (making the later `swiftlint` call if it succeeds not need to do another such lookup).

Comment: For what it's worth, I would not, myself, make it the makefile's job to set up swiftlint or check for its availability.  I would just attempt to run it, and *maybe* print a little extra information if that failed.  Instructions about downloading and setting up swiftlint should be in the build docs, and maybe also in makefile comments.  It is already the builders's responsibility to do that if they want to lint the source code.

Comment: Furthermore, linting is unlikely to be of interest to anyone who just wants to use the program.  It's fine to have a target for that in the makefile, but the audience is first and foremost yourself, and secondarily other project developers.  It's entirely reasonable to have higher expectations for such people than for random builders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every physical line in a recipe is executed by a separate shell instance. You need (mostly) this entire recipe to be execute by one shell instance; for that you need to join the physical lines into a single logical line using line continuation.

```
lint:
    @echo "Checking with SwiftLint"
    if test -d "/opt/homebrew/bin/"; then \
        PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin/:${PATH}"; \
    fi; \
    export PATH; \
    if which swiftlint > /dev/null; then \
        swiftlint; \
    else \
        echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"; \
    fi
```

Notice the expicit semicolons; because the line continuation effectively erases the newlines from the command, you need command terminators so that the shell parses your command correctly.